# WSO2 ESB Gmail Connector initialization

Tags: wso2, google-oauth, wso2-esb

I am a greenhorn of WSO2 ESB and confusing with configuration of gmail connector.

Based on the document (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Gmail+Operations), I have to fill gmail init element as below,

[image: init element]

In my thought, the accessToken and refreshToken are only generated dynamically after user consent in OAuth2 and will expire in certain time. So why need to write these into init part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the integration use cases, One of the main issues is accesstokens getting expired and need human interaction to continue the service.

From connector side, This method added to renew the tokens using refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct the accesstoken and the refreshtoken are generated dynamically and the accesstoken only expired. There is an option to refresh the accessToken using refreshtoken in most of the API's. If the connector doesn't have any mechanism to create the accessToken  using refresh-token then user need to interact to do this part and to replace the accessToken every time after expiration. But Connectors doing this part itself dynamically. First time you need to give the accessToken and refresh-token to this configuration after that connector itself handle the refresh-token flow and create the accessToken using refresh-token. So this will omit the user interaction in middle.